# When and how do I lock a mortgage rate while shopping for a refinance?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, refinance, mortgage-rate

We're in the process of hunting around for a lender in our area (US) to refinance our mortgage with.

I'm having a hard time understanding the steps in the application process. In particular once I've call around and got a rate for a x year mortgage locked in for 30 days, what do I need to do before I can lock that rate (I don't want them move it on me!). Do I need to do the 1003 there and then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't get the lock until you submit the application.

Comment: Does that mean I should apply to lots of lenders ahead of time or I should apply as soon as I get a rate a like?

Comment: Ask them for their listed rates, then apply if you like the rate.  Have all the documentation necessary.